# Use a MemoryStream with a function that expects a Filestream

Tags: c#, .net, filestream, memorystream

I have some functions here that for example are defined as

```
private int WriteLogikParameterTyp(FileStream filestream)
```

which i can not change. I want them to write into a MemoryStream Object. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

FileStream is a concrete implementation.

But it's a private method so should be easy enough to change since you can find all internal uses? Suggest replacing method signature with Stream rather than FileStream.

Well... unless you create a tempory file, write to it then read it into memory.

Comment: That was just an example. That one is private and others are public. And there are a lot of them.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't change the function signature to accept a more generic type.. I'd suggest writing out to a temporary file and then reading the contents into a MemoryStream instance.

Comment: Apologies; I beat you to the tempory file solution. We must have hit 'submit' at the same time :)

Answer (score 0):

No.

If you do not have access to them, you could use reflector to find out how they work and implement your own version for a MemoryStream. Whether this is legal is another matter...

Comment: "Whether this is legal" - I'm sure nobody would arrest him :)

Answer (score 0):

No.  FileStream doesn't expose a constructor that can be called so you can't inherit from it in order to emulate it.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion;

Rename the method like this

```
private int WriteLogikParameterTyp_Ex(Stream stream);
```

Then recreate the original signature like;

```
private int WriteLogikParameterTyp(FileStream filestream)
{
     return WriteLogikParameterTyp_Ex(filestream);
}
```

Comment: Why not simply change the method signature? It would not break existing using code since FileStream is derived from Stream...

Comment: I'm assuming since he "can't change the method" he can't make it delegate either:). May the fastest finger win! :)